# validation_batch_size is equal to train_batch_size in training CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to save the model with the highest accuracy, I need to take a batch of validation data in each step to validation after each step to train, the training data set will be reused because of epoch, but **if** `train_batch_size` **equals to** `validation_batch_size`, the validation data set will also be reused? because the validation data set is far less than the training data set. How should I do it? I mean to reuse the validation set without any problems? Or I set different sizes separately.

```
MAX_EPOCH = 10
for epoch in range(MAX_EPOCH):
    # training
    train_step = int(80000 / TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE)
    train_loss, train_acc = 0, 0
    for step in range(epoch * train_step, (epoch + 1) * train_step):
        x_train, y_train = sess.run([x_train_batch, y_train_batch])
        train_summary, _, err, ac = sess.run([merged, train_op, loss, acc],
                                             feed_dict={x: x_train, y_: y_train,
                                                        mode: learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN,
                                                        global_step: step})
        train_loss += err
        train_acc += ac
        if (step + 1) % 100 == 0:
            train_writer.add_summary(train_summary, step)
    print("Epoch %d,train loss= %.2f,train accuracy=%.2f%%" % (
        epoch, (train_loss / train_step), (train_acc / train_step * 100.0)))

    # validation
    val_step = int(20000 / VAL_BATCH_SIZE)
    val_loss, val_acc = 0, 0
    for step in range(epoch * val_step, (epoch + 1) * val_step):
        x_val, y_val = sess.run([x_val_batch, y_val_batch])
        val_summary, err, ac = sess.run([merged, loss, acc],
                                        feed_dict={x: x_val, y_: y_val, mode: learn.ModeKeys.EVAL,
                                                   global_step: step})
        val_loss += err
        val_acc += ac
        if (step + 1) % 100 == 0:
            valid_writer.add_summary(val_summary, step)
    print(
        "Epoch %d,validation loss= %.2f,validation accuracy=%.2f%%" % (
            epoch, (val_loss / val_step), (val_acc / val_step * 100.0)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use a different batch size during evaluation.

That being said, you should use the same validation set every time you evaluate the model. Otherwise, the results can increase/decrease because the examples you evaluated on were inherently easier/more difficult compared to the previous evaluation.

Comment: I just modified my question, according to your meaning to add some code, the above code is right? Each epoch I have 20000 validation set samples iteration finished to validate, finally save the most accurate epoch of the model? And in another question I showed out all my code maybe you could look at [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953858/how-to-adjust-parameters-when-the-cnn-model-is-over-fitting).