# TensorFlow CNN: Why validation loss are significantly different from the start and has been increasing?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

This is a classification model for ten categories of pictures. My code has three files, one is the CNN model convNet.py, one is read_TFRecord.py to read data, one is train.py to train and evaluation model. Training set of samples of 80,000, validation set of sample of 20,000.

Question:

In the first epoch:

training loss = 2.11, train accuracy = 25.61%

validation loss = 3.05, validation accuracy = 8.29%

Why validation loss are significantly different right from the start? And why the validation accuracy is always below 10%?

In the 10 epoch of training:

The training process is always in normal learning. The validation loss in the slow increase, the validation accuracy has been shock in about 10%. Is it over-fitting? But I have taken some measures, such as adding regularized losses,  droupout. I do not know where the problem is. I hope you can help me.

convNet.py:

```
def convNet(features, mode):
    input_layer = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 100, 100, 3])
    tf.summary.image('input', input_layer)

    # conv1
    with tf.name_scope('conv1'):
         conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
             inputs=input_layer,
             filters=32,
             kernel_size=5,
             padding="same",
             activation=tf.nn.relu,
             kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01),
             name='conv1'
         )
         conv1_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'conv1')
         tf.summary.histogram('kernel', conv1_vars[0])
         tf.summary.histogram('bias', conv1_vars[1])
         tf.summary.histogram('act', conv1)

    # pool1  100->50
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2, name='pool1')

    # dropout
    pool1_dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
    inputs=pool1, rate=0.5, training=tf.equal(mode, learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN), name='pool1_dropout')

    # conv2
    with tf.name_scope('conv2'):
         conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
             inputs=pool1_dropout,
             filters=64,
             kernel_size=5,
             padding="same",
             activation=tf.nn.relu,
             kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01),
             name='conv2'
         )
         conv2_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'conv2')
         tf.summary.histogram('kernel', conv2_vars[0])
         tf.summary.histogram('bias', conv2_vars[1])
         tf.summary.histogram('act', conv2)

    # pool2  50->25
    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2, name='pool2')

    # dropout
    pool2_dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
    inputs=pool2, rate=0.5, training=tf.equal(mode, learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN), name='pool2_dropout')

    # conv3
    with tf.name_scope('conv3'):
         conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(
             inputs=pool2_dropout,
             filters=128,
             kernel_size=3,
             padding="same",
             activation=tf.nn.relu,
             kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01),
             name='conv3'
         )
         conv3_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'conv3')
         tf.summary.histogram('kernel', conv3_vars[0])
         tf.summary.histogram('bias', conv3_vars[1])
         tf.summary.histogram('act', conv3)

    # pool3  25->12
    pool3 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv3, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2, name='pool3')

    # dropout
    pool3_dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
    inputs=pool3, rate=0.5, training=tf.equal(mode, learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN), name='pool3_dropout')

    # conv4
    with tf.name_scope('conv4'):
         conv4 = tf.layers.conv2d(
             inputs=pool3_dropout,
             filters=128,
             kernel_size=3,
             padding="same",
             activation=tf.nn.relu,
             kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01),
             name='conv4'
         )
         conv4_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'conv4')
         tf.summary.histogram('kernel', conv4_vars[0])
         tf.summary.histogram('bias', conv4_vars[1])
         tf.summary.histogram('act', conv4)

    # pool4  12->6
    pool4 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv4, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2, name='pool4')

    # dropout
    pool4_dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
    inputs=pool4, rate=0.5, training=tf.equal(mode, learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN), name='pool4_dropout')

    pool4_flat = tf.reshape(pool4_dropout, [-1, 6 * 6 * 128])

    # fc1
    with tf.name_scope('fc1'):
         fc1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool4_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                          kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01),
                          kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.01),
                          name='fc1')
         fc1_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'fc1')
         tf.summary.histogram('kernel', fc1_vars[0])
         tf.summary.histogram('bias', fc1_vars[1])
         tf.summary.histogram('act', fc1)

    # dropout
    fc1_dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
    inputs=fc1, rate=0.3, training=tf.equal(mode, learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN), name='fc1_dropout')

    # fc2
    with tf.name_scope('fc2'):
         fc2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=fc1_dropout, units=512, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                          kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01),
                          kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.01),
                          name='fc2')
         fc2_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'fc2')
         tf.summary.histogram('kernel', fc2_vars[0])
         tf.summary.histogram('bias', fc2_vars[1])
         tf.summary.histogram('act', fc2)

    # dropout
    fc2_dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
    inputs=fc2, rate=0.3, training=tf.equal(mode, learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN), name='fc2_dropout')

    # logits
    with tf.name_scope('out'):
         logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=fc2_dropout, units=10, activation=None,
                             kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01),
                             kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.01),
                             name='out')
         out_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, 'out')
         tf.summary.histogram('kernel', out_vars[0])
         tf.summary.histogram('bias', out_vars[1])
         tf.summary.histogram('act', logits)

     return logits
```

read_TFRecord.py:

```
def read_and_decode(filename, width, height, channel):
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename])
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example,
                                   features={
                                       'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                                       'img_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                                   })
img = tf.decode_raw(features['img_raw'], tf.uint8)
img = tf.reshape(img, [width, height, channel])
img = tf.cast(img, tf.float16) * (1. / 255) - 0.5
label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int16)
return img, label
```

train.py:

```
# step 1
TRAIN_TFRECORD = 'F:/10-image-set2/train.tfrecords'  # train data set
VAL_TFRECORD = 'F:/10-image-set2/val.tfrecords'  # validation data set
WIDTH = 100  # image width
HEIGHT = 100  # image height
CHANNEL = 3  # image channel
TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = 64
VAL_BATCH_SIZE = 16
train_img, train_label = read_and_decode(TRAIN_TFRECORD, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 
                         CHANNEL)
val_img, val_label = read_and_decode(VAL_TFRECORD, WIDTH, HEIGHT, CHANNEL)
x_train_batch, y_train_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([train_img, 
                               train_label], batch_size=TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE, 
                               capacity=80000,min_after_dequeue=79999, 
                               num_threads=64,name='train_shuffle_batch')
x_val_batch, y_val_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([val_img, val_label],
                           batch_size=VAL_BATCH_SIZE, 
                           capacity=20000,min_after_dequeue=19999, 
                           num_threads=64, name='val_shuffle_batch')

# step 2
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, WIDTH, HEIGHT, CHANNEL], 
                   name='x')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, ], name='y_')
mode = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='mode')
step = tf.get_variable(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32,     initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), name='step')
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_STEP, step)
logits = convNet(x, mode) 
with tf.name_scope('Reg_losses'):
     reg_losses = tf.cond(tf.equal(mode, learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN),
                     lambda: tf.add_n(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)),
                     lambda: tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32))
with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
     loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=y_, logits=logits) + reg_losses
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss, step)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.cast(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.int32), y_)
with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
     acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

# step 3
tf.summary.scalar("reg_losses", reg_losses)
tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", acc)
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

# step 4
with tf.Session() as sess:
     summary_dir = './logs/summary/'

     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
     saver = tf.train.Saver()   
     saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=1)

     train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(summary_dir + 'train',
                                     sess.graph)
     valid_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(summary_dir + 'valid')

     coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
     threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord) 
     max_acc = 0
     MAX_EPOCH = 10
     for epoch in range(MAX_EPOCH):
         # training
         train_step = int(80000 / TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE)
         train_loss, train_acc = 0, 0
         for step in range(epoch * train_step, (epoch + 1) * train_step):
             x_train, y_train = sess.run([x_train_batch, y_train_batch])
             train_summary, _, err, ac = sess.run([merged, train_op, loss, acc],
                                             feed_dict={x: x_train, y_: y_train,
                                                        mode: learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN,
                                                        global_step: step})
            train_loss += err
            train_acc += ac
            if (step + 1) % 50 == 0:
                train_writer.add_summary(train_summary, step)
         print("Epoch %d,train loss= %.2f,train accuracy=%.2f%%" % (
          epoch, (train_loss / train_step), (train_acc / train_step * 100.0)))

         # validation
         val_step = int(20000 / VAL_BATCH_SIZE)
         val_loss, val_acc = 0, 0
         for step in range(epoch * val_step, (epoch + 1) * val_step):
             x_val, y_val = sess.run([x_val_batch, y_val_batch])
             val_summary, err, ac = sess.run([merged, loss, acc],
                                        feed_dict={x: x_val, y_: y_val, mode: learn.ModeKeys.EVAL,
                                                   global_step: step})
             val_loss += err
             val_acc += ac
             if (step + 1) % 50 == 0:
                 valid_writer.add_summary(val_summary, step)
         print(
           "Epoch %d,validation loss= %.2f,validation accuracy=%.2f%%" % (
            epoch, (val_loss / val_step), (val_acc / val_step * 100.0)))

         # save model
         if val_acc > max_acc:
             max_acc = val_acc
             saver.save(sess, summary_dir + '/10-image.ckpt', epoch)
             print("model saved")
coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

Tensorboard result:

(Orange is train.Blue is validation.)

[accuracy-loss-reg_losses-conv1-conv2-conv3-conv4-fc1-fc2-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1uZk.jpg)

My data:

[train-val](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLfBy.jpg)

Comment: I reorganized the code with the picture, all the code with the data set I use screenshots are displayed. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this is an issue of overfitting - the losses are significantly different right from the start and diverge further well before you get through your first epoch (~500 batches). Without seeing your dataset its difficult to say more, though as a first step I'd encourage you to visualize both training and evaluation input data to make sure the issue isn't something there. The fact that you get significantly less than 10% on a 10-class classification problem initially indicates you almost certainly don't have something wrong here.

Having said that, you will likely run into problems with overfitting using this model because, despite what you may think, you aren't using dropout or regularization.

Dropout: `mode == learn.ModeKeys` is false if mode is a tensor, so you're not using dropout ever. You could use `tf.equals(mode, learn.ModeKeys)`, but I think you'd be much better off passing a `training` bool tensor to your convNet and feeding in the appropriate value.

Regularization: you're creating the regularization loss terms and they're being added to the `tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` collection, but the loss you're minimizing doesn't use them. Add the following:

```
loss += tf.add_n(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES))
```

before you optimize.

A note on the optimization `step`: you shouldn't be feeding in a value to the session run like you are. Every time you run to optimization operation it will update the value passed to `step` when you created it, so just create it with an int variable and leave it alone. See the following example code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.get_variable(shape=(4, 3), dtype=tf.float32,
                    initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(), name='x')
loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(x)
step = tf.get_variable(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32,
                       initializer=tf.zeros_initializer(), name='step')
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_STEP, step)  # good practice

opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss, step)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    step_val = sess.run(step)
    print(step_val)  # 0
    sess.run(opt)
    step_val = sess.run(step)
    print(step_val)  # 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely. On the dropout with regularization you are right, But I get a similar result after I modified the Dropout and Regularization. Here I am in order to let train_step and val_step equal, so will TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE set to 160, VAL_BATCH_SIZE set to 40, is this reason? If train_step and val_step are not equal, tensorboard shows that the two curves can not be compared because of the abscissa.

Comment: The accuracy is an average, so that shouldn't be affected. Your loss will be different. You're having issues because you're feeding in an artificial step from your for loop - you should let the optimization op handle the step update. See updated answer.

Comment: I'm really sorry. My computer gpu burned the last time to fix it. Thank you very much for your patience to answer, you taught me a lot. I have changed my code again as you said, but still get the same result, can you help me again? Whether the problem appears in the third line from the bottom of read_TFRecord.py:  `img = tf.cast(img, tf.float16) * (1. / 255) - 0.5` Here I read the data when doing a similar to the normalized processing, but this method I also use in the read validation data set.

Comment: And you say you doubt that my data is a problem, how can I use tensorboard to show you my data, you mean tensorboard IMAGES menu bar?

Comment: That's one way. You'll also have to add summary ops to the graph, and include writing them to file in your training loop. As a simpler step I'd just run the input tensor ops in the session and visualize the resulting numpy arrays using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`.

Comment: You are right, There is a problem with the data. I use the correct data to re-train the model to validate that the validation accuracy is easy to reach 60%, although after the model is difficult to continue to learn, training losses no longer reduce. Finally, I have a problem, that is, I said above, when I read the validation data to validate the model , I need to remove this line of code:`img = tf.cast(img, tf.float16) * (1. / 255) - 0.5`? Thanks a lot. You saved my day.

Comment: That normalisation line is good for learning, but will screw with the visualisation. Either change your visualisation to invert that process, or just remember to put the normalisation line back in for training. Now that you've got something working you're up to the hard part: making it work -well-. There's no simple answer to that. Read papers. See what other people are doing. The only thing I'd say is be careful of using float16 unless you really need to. It can work, but Float32 is the standard for ML.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your suggestion. You taught me a lot. Thank you for everything. :-)